# Не ясна логика Collections.sort()

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции

В список заношу стринги, сортирую .sort()-ом ожидаю увидеть прорядок но не вижу его

```
private static ArrayList<String> strings;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("Rumba");
    strings.add("Boom");
    strings.add("Madrid");
    strings.add("Kuragas");
    strings.add("Lambdarok");
    strings.add("Rom");
    strings.add("Zambialux");
    strings.add("Do");
    strings.add("Ken");
    strings.add(".");

     strings.forEach(System.out::println);
     Collections.sort(strings);
     strings.forEach(System.out::println);
     }
```

почему вместо :

> Do
>   Ken
>   Rom
>   Boom
>   Rumba
>   Madrid
>   Kuragaz
>   Lambdarok
>   Zambialux

Я вижу :

> Boom
>   Do
>   Ken
>   Kuragas
>   Lambdarok
>   Madrid
>   Rom
>   Rumba
>   Zambialux

Скажите пожалуйста. Или укажите что почитать, если знаете.

Comment: Я получил алфавитную сортировку, вот в чём дело.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию строки сортируются в лексикографическом порядке.

Сначала идет сравнение по первой букве. Чем она раньше в алфавите - тем строка будет раньше в результирующем списке.

Если первые буквы одинаковые - сравниваются следующие и т.д.

[Подробнее о лексикографическом порядке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Если хочется сортировать по длине строки - можно создать класс, имплементирующий интерфейс [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) и передать его экземпляр вторым аргументом в вызов `Collections.sort`.

Или можно вторым параметром передать лямбду, которая также будет явно сравнивать строки по длине:

```
Collections.sort(strings, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));
```

Comment: Спсибо конечно, но как Вы видите я только что минут 20-ть тупил разбираясь с простейшей сортировкой, так-что лямбда, компаратор и проч для меня это пока где-тот рядом с китайской грамматикой

Comment: @CoffeJava в лямбдах нет ничего страшного. добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало )

Comment: @CoffeJava В дополнение: заголовные буквы "старше" незаглавных при использовании sorted() без параметров. Поэтому при сортировке сначала будут отсортированные заглавные, затем отсортированные незаглавные